# A nullable expression can't be used as a condition. A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, nullable

I'm a beginner to flutter please someone help!

Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
color: isDone ? Color(0xFF7349FE) : Colors.transparent,

```
class TodoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? text;
  final bool? isDone;

  TodoWidget({this.text, @required this.isDone});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 24.0,
        vertical: 8.0,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 20.0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 12.0,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isDone ? Color(0xFF7349FE) : Colors.transparent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
            ),
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage(
                'assets/images/check_icon.png'
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
              text ??"(Unnamed Todo)",
              style: TextStyle(
                color:  Color(0xFF211551),
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A todo will always be done or not-done, there's no case where a todo can be neither.

So instead of keeping `isDone` nullable, keep a default value for isDone. This way you only have to code the widget for `true` or `false` cases, and not for the `null` case.

change the declaration to make it non-nullable:

```
final bool isDone;
```

change the constructor to make it false by default:

```
TodoWidget({this.text, this.isDone = false});
```

Comment: You don't need the required tag if you are giving it a default value. Either use `required` or the default value. Not both.

Comment: Fixed it @eNeM, code copy mistake. 

Answer (score 0):

Dart is a language which uses null safety. When you declaring `bool? isDone;` you are giving `?` here. It means `isDone` boolean can be null ( It means it can contain `null` other than `true` or `false` ).So, when you are using this variable in a condition which only accepts `true` or `false` it may provide `null`.

So, here the best thing to do is gave a default value to the `isDone` variable. Like
`bool isDone = false;` . Don't forgot to remove `?`.

Don't forgot to gave tick if you find this helpful. Any doubts comment.

Just change this:

Before:
`bool? isDone;`

After:
`bool isDone = false;` or `bool isDone = true` . It depends on your purpose.

Comment: Can u edit it in my code cause it's still not fixed!!

Comment: I edited it. check it. Still not fixed then comment again.

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Post what is the error and what you want to try.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try like this way**

class TodoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 final String? text;
 final bool? isDone = false;

 TodoWidget({this.text, @required this.isDone});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 24.0,
    vertical: 8.0,
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 20.0,
        height: 20.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          right: 12.0,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isDone ?? true ? Color(0xFF7349FE) : Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
        ),
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage(
            'assets/images/check_icon.png'
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text(
          text ??"(Unnamed Todo)",
          style: TextStyle(
            color:  Color(0xFF211551),
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
      ),

    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```